# Expansion in power series of $z=0$

Tags: power-series

How do I expand this function in power series?

$$f(x):= \frac{1}{1+x+x^2+x^3}.$$

I have tried to factorize it and we have

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{-1+x}{x^2+1}\right)$$

however I am not sure if it leads anywhere, because the other expression has an $x$ in the counter and I do not know how to use $1/(1-x)$ series expansion.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1-x^4}=(1-x)\sum_{k\geq 0} x^{4k}$

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is the generating function of $1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ while $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is the generating function of $1,0,-1,0,1,0\ldots$  and $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is the generating function of $0,1,0,-1,0,1,\ldots$.  So add them together and divide by $2$

Comment: Kelenner, is that a well known fact? Could you explain where it comes from?

Comment: @RyszardEggink Yes, it is a [well known fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)